# Get part description from OctoPart API in C#

Tags: c#, api, get

I am using Octopart API, every thing is fine. But can not get part description from it. 
Here is my MVC Controller Code for simplicity.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search() {
    string data = Request["search"];
    int itemsCounter = 0;
    String ApiKey = "abc";
    int resultss = 0;
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    var json = new { mpn = data };
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    string url = "https://octopart.com/api/v3/parts/match?apikey="+ApiKey+"&queries=[" + js.Serialize(json) + "]&pretty_print=true";
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
        WebRequest.Create(url);
    try {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
            request.GetResponse();
        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        string tempString = null;
        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            if (count != 0)
            {
                tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

                sb.Append(tempString);
            }
        }
        while (count > 0);

        var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(sb.ToString());

        ViewBag.response = results["results"];
    }catch (Exception) {
        //return "OctoPart API not responding, try again.";
    }
    return View("Index");
}
```

I get search results from post request and send a GET request to Octopart API with API key and search query. It return matched results, if found. Results contains matching parts details without description.

Can anybody help to get part description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation: https://octopart.com/api/docs/v3/overview#how-to-use

**Descriptions**

> For perfomance reasons, part descriptions are not included in API responses by default. To include part descriptions you can use the include url argument:

Example:

```
$ curl -G https://octopart.com/api/v3/parts/match \
   -d queries="[{\"mpn\":\"SN74S74N\"}]" \
   -d apikey=EXAMPLE_KEY \
   -d pretty_print=true \
   -d include[]=descriptions
```

> When a description is available it will be attached to the part object
>   it belongs to. Here is the result of the API request described above:

Sample JSON is too long for posting. Just checkout the link.

I don't really know the C# equivalent since I do not know the API but it should be possible. You might already know how to add `include[]=descriptions`. By the looks of it is simple query string parameter.

Comment: @QaisarShabbir Welcome. If this is the one you need then don't forget to mark it as the correct answer.